# Python don't work after awaking from sleep

Tags: python, windows

I have written a live dictionary script which works perfect, I need it to be working all the time and assigned a hotkey `Ctrl + 0` to it, whenever this key pressed dictionary ask to select a word and hence it translate and do everything

Now, the question is, if I sleep my pc(windows) and after awaking it from sleep pressing `Ctrl + 0`
doesn't do anything, I have seen in pycharm that no exception occur, the script seems to go somewhere infinity, well after quick awake from sleep like 10minutes it works

Moreover, the task manager says that script is running and even take the same amount of ram as seen before

Comment: Maybe the python ate much before sleeping

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried closing it and opening it again. Restarting should solve most problems. When task manager says it is running, it doesn't mean it will actually work. Running a live script then "stopping" it halfway can cause disruptions.

Comment: Yeah restarting script obviously work but it is very inconvenient to open dictionary each time I login